# Remove element via PHP str_replace and regex

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I think my the regex is off (not very good at regex yet). What I'm trying to do is remove the first and last `<section>` tags (though this is set to replace all, if it worked). I set it up like this so it would completely remove any attributes of the tag, along with the closing tag.

**The code:**

```
//Remove from string
$content = "<section><p>Test</p></section>";
$section = "<(.*?)section(.*?)>";
$output= str_replace($section, "", $content);
echo $output;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml/3577662#3577662

Comment: I'm completely confused about the link and why this is getting downvotes.. I just want to remove a section tag to fix a glitch in my program. This seemed like a good way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Try this:

```
print strip_tags($content, '<section>');
```